# Can Decision Trees be used to Identify Clusters ("Cohorts") within the Data?

Tags: r, clustering, survival, cart

I have the following question: **Can Decision Trees be used to identify Clusters ("Cohorts") within the Data?**

I present my question in the context of Survival Analysis Regression (using the R programming language). Suppose we take the "veteran" dataset that contains bio-medical information and survival times on war veterans collected during a medical study:

```
#load libraries
library(survival)

 head(veteran)
  trt celltype time status karno diagtime age prior
1   1 squamous   72      1    60        7  69     0
2   1 squamous  411      1    70        5  64    10
3   1 squamous  228      1    60        3  38     0
4   1 squamous  126      1    60        9  63    10
5   1 squamous  118      1    70       11  65    10
6   1 squamous   10      1    20        5  49     0
```

In the above dataset, the veterans were classified into "cohorts" based on the treatment ("trt") they received. But suppose we wanted to consider alternate methods to create "cohorts" within the data.

I am wondering if the following strategy makes sense:

**1)** Run a (regression) decision tree algorithm on this data and see which terminal nodes of the decision tree the veterans fall under.

**2)** Provided that the decision tree from **step 1)** fits the data well, create a separate regression model for veterans in each terminal nodes. Consider pruning and collapsing several terminal nodes into a single node if some of the terminal nodes are sparsely populated.

I illustrate this strategy below:

**1) Create Decision Tree**

```
#load libraries
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

#fit regression decision tree
tree = rpart( time ~., data = veteran,   control = rpart.control(minsplit = 20, cp = 0.005,  xval = 0), parms = list(split = "gini"))

#plot tree
rpart.plot(tree)
```

[image]

The corresponding 4 cohorts ("rules") identified in this tree are:

```
rpart.rules(tree)

 time                                                  
   43 when celltype is smallcell or adeno & karno <  55
   91 when celltype is smallcell or adeno & karno >= 55
  111 when celltype is  squamous or large & karno <  65
  255 when celltype is  squamous or large & karno >= 65
```

And we can see how well this tree fits the data:

```
printcp(tree)

Regression tree:
rpart(formula = time ~ ., data = veteran, parms = list(split = "gini"), 
    control = rpart.control(minsplit = 50, cp = 0.005, xval = 0))

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] celltype karno   

Root node error: 3387232/137 = 24724

n= 137 

        CP nsplit rel error
1 0.135786      0   1.00000
2 0.094872      1   0.86421
3 0.012502      2   0.76934
4 0.005000      3   0.75684
```

**2)** **Creating Individual Survival Models**

We can isolate the rows from the original data corresponding to the 4 cohorts that were identified:

```
    #cohort 1
    
    cohort_1 <- veteran[which((veteran$celltype == "smallcell" |  veteran$celltype  == "adeno") & veteran$karno < 55   ), ]

cohort_1$cohort = 1
cohort_1$cohort = as.factor(cohort_1$cohort)
    
    #cohort 2
    
    cohort_2 <- veteran[which((veteran$celltype == "smallcell" |  veteran$celltype  == "adeno") & veteran$karno > 55   ), ]

cohort_2$cohort = 2
cohort_2$cohort = as.factor(cohort_2$cohort)
    
    #cohort 3
    
    cohort_3 <- veteran[which((veteran$celltype == "squamous" |  veteran$celltype  == "large") & veteran$karno < 65   ), ]

cohort_3$cohort = 3
cohort_3$cohort = as.factor(cohort_3$cohort)
    
    #cohort 4
    
    cohort_4 <- veteran[which((veteran$celltype == "squamous" |  veteran$celltype  == "large") & veteran$karno > 65   ), ]

cohort_4$cohort = 4
cohort_4$cohort = as.factor(cohort_4$cohort)

#merge together
cohort_data = rbind(cohort_1, cohort_2, cohort_3, cohort_4)
```

Then, we can fit individual survival models to each of the 4 cohorts and visualize the results:

```
library(ggfortify)

#cohort level analysis
km_trt_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ cohort, data= cohort_data)

#visualize results

autoplot(km_trt_fit, main = "Survival Times by Cohort")
```

[image]

**Question:** Does what I have done make sense? Or was this completely unnecessary and it would have been better to just use a Survival Decision Tree (e.g. https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v083i12/v83i12.pdf)? In general, is it advisable to identify sub-populations (i.e. cohorts) within the data using decision trees, and fitting models to the observations belonging to each of these sub-populations (i.e. the terminal nodes)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In principle, applying the strategy you outline is possible and may sometimes also lead to useful insights. However, the main drawback is that you don't exploit all information you have about the data, in particular you ignore the censoring information when learning the tree. Hence, this will usually lead to suboptimal partitions/clusterings of the data.

Instead you should at least incorporate the censoring information and employ a splitting criterion that leverages this. One option to do so is to use the `ctree()` function from the `partykit` package which supports survival trees with basic Kaplan-Meier fits in each of the resulting partitions of the tree. See also: Hothorn, Hornik, Zeileis (2006). "Unbiased Recursive Partitioning: A Conditional Inference Framework." *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **15**(3), 651-674. [doi:10.1198/106186006X133933](https://doi.org/10.1198/106186006X133933). Replication material is also available in `vignette("ctree", package = "partykit")`.

Moreover, it would be possible to fit model-based survival trees (e.g., fitting a Weibull or Cox proportional hazards model) in each of the partitions and employing a suitable splitting criterion. See `vignette("mob", package = "partykit")` for a worked example. Finally, you could even fit a survival treatment model (`Surv(time, status) ~ trt`) and partition the data based on that using the `model4you` package.

The basic survival tree in `partykit` can be constructed as follows:

```
## packages and data
library("partykit")
library("survival")
## all categorical variables should be factors
veteran <- transform(veteran, trt = factor(trt), prior = factor(prior))
## fit tree with 1% significance level
ct <- ctree(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran, minsplit = 20, alpha = 0.01)
plot(ct)
```

[image: survival ctree]

If you want to create a factor with the predicted node IDs, e.g., for further subsequent grouped analyses, you can easily do so:

```
## factor coding groups based on node IDs
veteran$node <- factor(predict(ct, type = "node"))
## grouped Kaplan-Meier curves
km <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ node, data = veteran)
library("ggfortify")
autoplot(km)
```

[image: fitted Kaplan-Meier curves in terminal nodes of the tree]